# Conflict AVFoundation and AppKit Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I am a novice, trying to code in Swift.  This site has been invaluable, but now I have run into a problem for which I have not been able to find a solution.

I am working with video metadata, and I am having a curious problem when trying to utilize AVFoundation and AppKit together in Swift.  I have isolated the problem in a Swift playground as follows:

This code works, with the value "My title" successfully assigned to testitem:

```
import AVFoundation

var testitem = AVMutableMetadataItem()

testitem.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifieriTunesMetadataSongName
testitem.value = "My title"
```

Just by adding "import AppKit" statement results in an error:

```
import AVFoundation
import AppKit

var testitem = AVMutableMetadataItem()

testitem.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifieriTunesMetadataSongName
testitem.value = "My title"
```

Error: "Cannot assign to 'value' in 'testitem'.  It seems the value property of testitem is no longer recognized.

What is going on here? Is there some incompatibility between AppKit and AVFoundation?
Incidentally , playing around with this I get the same error if I replace import AppKit with import AVKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that, once you import AppKit or AVKit, `value` is being subsumed in the compiler's mind by the function, `value()`, from NSDictionaryControllerKeyValuePair (which is part of that import).

You can work around the problem easily by calling `setValue()`, e.g.

```
testitem.setValue("My title")
```

Note that you will have to treat `value` as a function in order to get it, e.g. `println(testitem.value())`.

As you can well imagine, this is not an issue in Objective-C, because setting the `value` property in Objective-C is *the same* as calling `setValue:`. But the Swift compiler doesn't work quite the same way. In Swift you can see either the getter/setter functions or the property but not both. I would suggest reporting this to Apple as a bug in the API.

Comment: And it was an interesting question too!